Next/14 android/arm64 SWC failed to load
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/67605
Disabling swcMinify in config resulted in this beautiful output:
~/test/my-app $ npm run dev

> my-app@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

  ▲ Next.js 14.2.4
  - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Starting...
 ⚠ Disabling SWC Minifer will not be an option in the next major version. Please report any issues you may be experiencing to https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues
 ⚠ Attempted to load @next/swc-android-arm64, but it was not installed
 ⨯ Failed to load SWC binary for android/arm64, see more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/failed-loading-swc


Swc for android not updated for Next.js 14 yet. But, i updated to Next.js 15 RC now it can run on termux
